# Import product with media/catalog/product folder

Tags: magento-1.8, import, importexport, media

We have 2 servers. Some changes made in the product name, category changes and custom_options in the first server.  So we need to import the products with images in the second server which is exported from the first server.  How to do products import with media/catalog/product folder images in magento import?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want to achieve, because right now I don't understand why not use mysqldump / mysql load and scp of images from one server to another.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is still a mess in magento. Especially because you don't want to loose the FKs on the order items, this means you can't import/export and have somehow to override the settings in the database.

What you can try (offline and localy first!) is to dump all the `catalog_*` tables, set magento in maintenance mode (create a `maintenance.flag` in root) and then write the dump back to the server.

**IF** the server is a copy of the old database. If they only have the same data but not the same IDs I think you are lost and the only way is to copy it over by hand, because implementing a script which does it costs more time.